Is it possible to perform conditional unpacking in python?
I'm currently doing an interface between several API in a python project.
really basically, at some point, I have to call a method from a "Builder" object. There are two types of builders, a GetBuilder and an AggregateBuilder (I'm using the Weaviate API for people wondering). They both allow me to setup an hybrid search as follow :
search_settings = {param_1: value_1, param_2: value_2, ...}

get_builder = get_builder.with_hybrid(**search_settings)
aggregate_builder = aggregate_builder.with_hybrid(search_settings)

Notice that the only difference between the two syntax is the dict unpacking for the GetBuilder.
My question is general: is there a clean way to perform conditional unpacking ?
So far, the only options I have found are :
1 if - else
aggregate: bool
builder: GetBuilder | AggregateBuilder

if aggregate:
    builder = builder.with_hybrid(settings)
else:
    builder = builder.with_hybrid(**settings)

Efficient, clear, but I feel It's redundant
2 using eval
aggregate: bool
builder: GetBuilder | AggregateBuilder

builder = eval("builder.with_hybrid({}settings)".format("**"*(not aggregate)))

Works, but unclear and the eval function just feels wrong to use
Is there another way to perform a conditional unpacking cleanly ?

builder = builder.with_hybrid(**(dict(content=settings) if aggregate else settings))

Definitely not eval. Short of anything from the library itself (the differing signatures seems like a weird design decision), I'd define my own wrapper around one of them so that you can always pass a dict (or always pass unpacked key-value pairs) to either.

Thank you for your quick responses, I'll work with them

It is not clear what you want to do as the method seems to accept both ways already. Is the method in your hands, i.e. is it your code, or not? It's your code and you want a clean way for it to accept both a mapping and keyword args?

@Pynchia to be clear this inconsistency does not come from my code (it is from the weaviate-client library). There is not a single method that accept both ways, but two separate methods of two separate objects with the same name, but with different way of passing parameters. As mentioned by chepner, it really seems like a weird design decision.

Option 1 looks good to me. If you want to make a single call to builder.with_hybrid() you could do the following:
if aggregate:
    args, kwargs = [settings], {}
else:
    args, kwargs = [], settings

builder.with_hybrid(*args, **kwargs)



I'll make a single call to builder.with_hybrid() anyways, and I think there is a loss in clarity in your suggestion, but thanks for suggesting something new.
